# Use of undeclared identifier 'action' when initializing a UISwipeGestureRecognizer in another object

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, sprite-kit

I am attempting to create a UISwipeGestureRecognizer in my ViewController's viewDidLoad that will use a selector to call a method in another object (MyScene).  I am, however, receiving the following error:

> Use of undeclared identifer 'action'

Is there is a reason that this is not working?

Sample code:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
if (!skView.scene) {
  skView.showsFPS = YES;
  skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

  // Create and configure the scene.
  SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
  scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
  // Present the scene.
  [skView presentScene:scene];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(MyScene) action:@selector(screenSwipedRight)];
    swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeRight)];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(MyScene) action:@selector(screenSwipedLeft)];
    swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeLeft)];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(MyScene) action:@selector(screenSwipedUp)];
    swipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeUp.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeUp)];
    }
}
```

I would be happy to provide any other information if more detail is needed.

Thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initWithTarget methods each say `initWithTarget:(MyScene)`. I presume you want to use `self` instead.

If you instead want your scene object to receive the events, then use:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:scene action:@selector(screenSwipedUp)];
```

Comment: Wouldn't "self" imply that the target is ViewController.m?  I am trying to use this UISwipeGestureRecognizer in MyScene.m.  The method referenced by @selector is also in the MyScene object.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter what the target is. If you change it to self then the object represented by `self` will be notified. If you want your "scene" object to be notified then you need to actually pass in that scene object into the method. Something like `initWithTarget:scene action:@selector(....`

Answer (score 2):

The target needs to be an instance of a class:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(MyScene) action:@selector(screenSwipedRight)];
```

Probably needs to be:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: scene action:@selector(screenSwipedRight)];
```

Merhod `screenSwipedRight` should be a publia method of class `MyScene`.